# How do you dynamically name and create an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

normally to create an object you would write:

```
function Dog(name) {  
  this.name = name;  
}  

fifi = new Dog("fifi");
```

How do I dynamically name the object so that I can write:

```
var name = "fifi";  
[name] = new Dog(name);
```

to achieve the same outcome as:

```
fifi = new Dog("fifi");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the object you're creating the variable on (a property, not just a variable) you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), like this:

```
var dogs = {};
dogs[name] = new Dog(name);
```

Later you could access it either way:

```
dogs.fifi
//or...
dogs["fifi"]
```

If it's a global variable you're after, that object (instead of `dogs` above) would just be `window`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nick.  In essence, we are creating a hash with dynamically named keys and values.  genius.

Answer (score 3):

This would do it:

```
function createDog(name, scope) {
    scope[name] = new Dog(name);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
createDog('fifi', window);
```

or pass any other object as your scope.

But I would not tie objects and variables to close together. One advantage of objects is that you can pass them freely around and several variables can have a reference to the same object.
I would give it a more meaningful name, that describes the *purpose* of that object.